# Add google translate string to all url's of a moodle site

Tags: jquery, .htaccess, url, moodle, google-translate

Need to have this string at the end of ALL site url's to trigger Google translate on a Moodle site, (ie needs to appear on every page):

```
#googtrans(en|fr)
```

I have seen a couple of methods on here to do similar things, using either .htaccess or jquery but haven't been able to replicate either.

Answer (score 0):

It depends slightly on what's in the rest of your htaccess, but this is roughly what you're after:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)googtrans\(en|fr\)(&|$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}#googtrans\(en|fr\) [L,QSA,R,NE]
</IfModule>
```

First line switches the engine on.
Second line checks if the URL doesn't have the appended googtrans.etc in it already.
Third line adds the annex provided that it passed the check in line 2.

the "NE" in the [L,QSA,R,**NE**] tag ensures that your brackets and hash are not coded so that they render correctly in the browser, being special characters.

This will not work out of the box and will probably require some tweaking but I hope it will be of some use to you.